# Reputation count for questions with 100+ rep overflows in "related questions" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

I did a cursory search, but couldn't find if this bug has been reported before.

On the "related questions" sidebar, questions that happen to have a reputation count of three or more digits is overflowing. For example, the post "[How can I tell people to get to the point](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9283/1531)" has 105 reputation, and displays as the below.

You can see this behavior on [this page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2282/1531). I'm currently running Firefox 29 on Windows 8.1.

Perhaps the gray box needs to be widened a bit?

[image: overflowing]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229751/related-questions-with-over-99-score-display-incorrectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, it will be live after our next production build